# UUID npm packg is returing undefined .. I want to make id for link i try to generate id but it's retruing undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, syntax-error

This is the model where I import the uuid pack

```
import * as uuid from "uuid";

export class Note {
  id: string;

  constructor(public title: string, public content: string) {
    this.id = uuid.v4();
  }
}
```

in the component class :

```
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from "@angular/router";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
 
export class EditNoteComponent implements OnInit {
    notes: Note[]
    constructor(private activateRouter: ActivateRouter)

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.activeRoute.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      const idParam = paramMap.get("id");
      console.log(idParam);
    });
  }
```

and in the HTML file where I put the link so when the user clicks the notecard it should give me a unique id something like (9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d) but then console only show undefine!!!

```
<div class="noteContainer">
    <div class="notes-lists">
      <a [routerLink]="[note.id]" *ngFor="let note of notes">
        <app-note-cards [note]="note"></app-note-cards>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already solved this months ago.. But, try putting this in your constructor:

```
activateRouter.params.subscribe(() => {
    if(route.snapshot.params.id){

        console.log(route.snapshot.params.id);
    }
);
```

I also notice that in your constructor parameters you have 'activateRouter' whereas in your ngOnInit you have 'activeRoute'